# Ошибка в SALVATTORE.JS и WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

> Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/rnmp/salvattore/master/dist/salvattore.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Ну могу понять, что надо сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в подключение скрипта. `type="text/javascript"`

Должно быть как то так

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/rnmp/salvattore/master/dist/salvattore.min.js"></script>
```